# is it possible to give margin-left css/scss dynamically to its Childs element on the basics of position (nth + 2px)

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a form which show Package Hierarchy, Package Input depend on package type so is it possible to give margin-left dynamically by css/sass to its Childs element on the basics of position

```
enter code here
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
     child one
    </div>
    <div class="child">
     child two
    </div>        
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
     child one
    </div>
    <div class="child">
     child two
    </div>        
    <div class="child">
     child three
    </div>
</div>
```

child may differ by type so feel unsuitable to give static :nth-child() css

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sass. You just need to take maximum amount of Childs into $elements.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
     child one
    </div>
    <div class="child">
     child two
    </div>        
    <div class="child">
     child three
    </div>
</div>
<style>
$elements: 15;
@for $i from 0 to $elements {
  .parent .child:nth-child(#{$i + 1}){
    margin-left: ($i * 2)+px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks you for answer 
using js i have done is design 
i am curious to know is there any class and element selectors to find the number of child it have

thank you again